# Random string gets repeated?

Tags: php, mysql, uniqueidentifier, base-conversion

I have a service on the internet where people post pictures and a short string is generated. Only one can be used ever. However, I am getting into duplicates in the database and I am seeing major problems.

Here's what I am using:

```
$id=rand(10000,99999);
$short_string = base_convert($id,20,36);
```

What would be the best way to fix it? Check from the database and keep looping till it doesn't match one? What if every possible solution and it goes in an infinite loop?

Comment: by the code you posted, you can only have 89999 numeric string ids. Not very many. Are these permanently in use? or do you remember and recycle them?

Comment: question: base_convert( string $number, int $frombase, int $tobase ). I may be missing something but isn't your frombase, base 10 and not 20?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: That's the code I use, exactly. What does changing the base from 10 to 20 do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment the last value by a random amount instead of using a random value. Like so:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM thetable ORDER BY theId DESC LIMIT 1");
$keyToUse = 1;
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $keyToUse = (int)$row['theId'] + rand(1, 100);
}
```

Then convert the integer key to and from any format, say using `base_convert`.

Comment: This is exactally what I did. Except I added 10 random numbers to it. I don't think it will get repeated any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

Put your PK through an algorithm that generates a unique number from it and put that through your function.

Comment: I do have ID for each image. So can I do something with that? Like generate something special like md5 but for really short. I could be using the wrong vocabulary, but you know what I mean. Remember: I need to keep it short as possible.

Comment: Zero-pad it to, say, 8 digits, reverse the digits, turn that back into a number, then convert it.

Comment: I get what all you are saying. Can you please post a short example or link that I can look at to get this working?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

Comment: Will this ensure I will get a random one each time?

Comment: No, since it will derive it from the PK of the entry. A more complex algorithm will result in less predictable values, but they will *always* be deterministic.

Comment: This is not to say that you can't use them, though. They *will* be unique per entry (depending on the algorithm, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The best bet would be to make sure the image doesn't exist by using the random number generator against the list of images before writing a new image with that number in it.

Try to increase the amount and type of characters by using an algorithm that uses numbers, letters so it increases the combinations that you can have.

Comment: But doesn't that still put it at risk for getting the same result more than once?

Comment: You can count in order of increasing numbers instead of random numbers if you truely want to never have repeating numbers but if you choose to go the random way there will always be a chance of having dups.

Comment: That would probably introduce a race condition if two processes were racing to insert the same value; both checks could succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `mt_rand()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php. Also you should be increasing the range.

Answer (score 0):

Use md5 http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php
The strings produced have no conflict (with large probability).

Comment: It needs to be URL-friendly. 1-6 characters long.

Comment: You can user urlEncode for the first part, but I am not sure if there is something robust for only 6 characters.

Comment: Here's a example URL: http://myflashpics.com/picture/8292 ... I cannot have a 20 - 40 character string.

Comment: Why not use an auto increment number? Is there really a need for randomness?

Comment: I have that. But I don't want users to have access to it -- I want a short string.